# Gatsby/NextJS: group pages by domains

Tags: next.js, gatsby

I'm trying to understand how to migrate to Gatsby/NextJS our structure.

```
src
├── scripts
├── components
├── domains
│   ├── ca.cdn.domain-1.com
│   │   ├── global
│   │   └── pages
│   │   │   ├── page.html
│   │   │   └── page-2.html
│   ├── m.cdn.domain-2.de
│   │   ├── global
│   │   └── pages
│   │   │   ├── page.html
│   │   │   └── page-2.html
```

**page.html** files can have *different* html templates, but sharing some common components from `src`.
Currently, we generate static pages per domain with Gulp. Tried Gatsby today and pages can be only in `src` folder. Any suggestions on how to use Gatsby/NextJS with multiple domains in 1 repo?

Also more detailed I described the question [here](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/discussions/12472) for NextJS.